# How to remove additional Comma in Text file casing data to Mismatch or Overflow to other Columns

Tags: c#

I have a text file that I would like to convert to CSV. When I examine the file in ***EXCEL Import Wizard*** the columns and rows looks like the below image:

[image]

When I read the file and write to file as .csv then it ends up like the below image, as displayed in the highlighted rows.

[image]

I noticed that some of the data in the file has multiple comma' which are the rows data that are running out of their place. This is beyond me.

I am using the following code:

```
class Program
{
static void AddComma(string s, TextWriter writer)
{
    foreach (string line in s.Replace("\"", "").Split('\n'))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            writer.Write(line[i]);
        }
        writer.WriteLine();
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\folder\sample.txt");
    string a = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();

    FileStream aFile = new FileStream(@"C:\folder\sample.csv", FileMode.Create);
    AddComma(a, new StreamWriter(aFile));
    aFile.Close();


}
}
```

***Found Solution Update:***

All I did was modified the following line of code:
I removed the Replace() Method.

From this: `foreach (string line in s.Replace("\"", "").Split('\n'))`

To this: `foreach (string line in s.Split('\n'))`

Also the array starts from zero so I changed the starting point of the counter or int:
Meaning instead of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
```

I have this:

```
            for (int i = -1; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > -1)
                writer.Write(line[i]);
            }
```

This ensure that I will also get the first column in the file beginning at zero.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are stripping the delimiting quotes. CSV files can have values quoted. When you have a comma in the value you need to quote it.

In your example, the file already appears to be in CSV format except for the file extension. I don't know if your actual production file is more complicated and requires more formatting. However, in this example it would simply require a file rename.

See [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) for pretty standard specifications. It's a little dense.

Comment: Huh. I suppose it never occurred to me that there'd be a spec for CSV. Never thought to look. Figured it was in the acronym. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Xenophile thanks for the tip: I fixed the problem by modifying the Replace method: See code.

Comment: How did you modify replace method.
is this as following - 
first split list by ",
then traverse each splite item - one by one and from 0-(n-2) items replace starting char by empty string if it starts with " and for n-1 ends with "
OR have you apply different method ?

Comment: @Tej Kiran: Please see above code: I know this sounds very common. But took me a while to get it working as I am still learning this stuff. Not sure this is the best but it works.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy OK I was thinking that you need to fetch the item to process but you just want to convert into csv format without changing enclosed char or terminated by char. I think the more better and easy process is to just rename it from txt to csv. Because unnecessary you are traversing each line from text file and then put in csv file. Just Try It

Comment: @Tej Kiran: Yes! I converted the file extension and change the name. That worked better and is so simple: This is the best damn thing I have done this week. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.